# Can the word 'quote' mean only one word?

Tags: word-usage

According to Google quote is '

> repeat or copy out (a group of words from a text or speech), typically
>   with an indication that one is not the original author or speaker'

can a single word qualify as a quote?

EDIT:
Besides: One word sentences like "yes","no","okay".

To put the question in perspective: The question came up when my co-worker and I were trying to use [this](http://citebite.com/) website and we were arguing if it is necessary to provide more than one word.

Comment: To rephrase, you want to know whether a single word can qualify as a quote? Short story, yes. Consider: *You want to borrow money? Seriously? Do you remember when I asked you if you could spot me $100 last month? You said, and I quote, "no'.".

Comment: I'll rephrase the question as you suggested :)

Comment: That's a cool resource, thanks for the link! As to your updated question, the answer is still incontestibly yes. Consider: *What were his last words? I'm not sure, I couldn't hear him too well, and he wasn't quite all there by the end, but I think he said "aardvark"*. Or consider that my first example wasn't quoting a one word sentence, but a single word from a longer sentence, as in the person who wants to borrow money from the speaker didn't just say no, he said *No, I won't lend you any money, I'm saving it to buy aardvarks*.

Comment: Quoth the raven, "Nevermore!"

Comment: @HotLicks And that word it's only single stock and store! Now *that* would make a great answer.

Comment: Quoted 21 times in *Citizen Kane*: "ROSEBUD!"

Comment: "NUTS!" –[Anthony McAuliffe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthony_McAuliffe)

Comment: [The answer _must_ be yes – I've seen it on a Tishirt.](https://www.lookhuman.com/design/58943-to-quote-hamlet-act-iii-scene-iii-line-87-no/tee) I'm not sure that the edited restriction is warranted. Surely, if 'Yes' qualifies as a quote, then any other sentence fragment (eg the answer to "What is a word meaning 'pertaining to stars'?") does. " 'Sidereal', according to Collins."

Comment: Also, one of the most famous one: "Eureka" as supposedly said by Archimedes. or more contemporary : " Adrieeeeeennne!"  (you have to say it like that) as said by that famous Oscar laureat. Everybody will know that you're quoting him. You don't even need to say that it's a quote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it's perfectly possible for a quote to be one word, and this is done frequently in reporting.

> The leader called the attacks "disgusting".

In this sentence the word "disgusting" is a quote, and is the only thing the leader is actually stated to have said.

Even simple words can be a quote.

> Asked if he was intending to run as a candidate, the politician said "Yes."

A single word quote can even stand on its own.

> Rosebud! <sub>*[Citizen Kane](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0033467/trivia?tab=qt&ref_=tt_trv_qu)*</sub>

Comment: So any part of a text can be quoted single words included?

Comment: @stsatlantis Yes. A quote is just that: a quote. A piece of speech or writing you're echoing and attributing back to its source.

Comment: I would upvote your comment but i don't have enough rep.